# Dealing with ads blocking application functionality on iPad

Tags: ipad, ui

I've noticed some applications on my iPad have advertisements. The problem is that the advertisement covers lower part of the screen where some applications place buttons and other UI elements, and the ad blocks there elements and prevents me from properly using the application. Is there any way to solve this - like move the ad somewhere or temporarily remove it? It's OK when the ads are just annoying but when they actually prevent me from using the application it's bad.

Answer (score 1):

If this problem happens in an App than your only chance is tell the developer of the app that the ad placement was a really bad user interface choice and to please fix this issue.

If you can provide screenshots and a brief description of when this happens (if it only happens under certain circumstances) they will most probably be very grateful and fix this problem ASAP.

Just as a precaution: be polite in your email and try to be as objective as possible when telling about your problem.